# Many to many in linq with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have 3 tables in a database:

[image of the database](http://houlahans.co.uk/Untitled.png)

I have been looking online for a long time trying to find out how in linq and vb.net how i can do a query that has access to both the event and individual table for example showing all the events individual 1 is taking part in ect. i was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction or know of any good tutorial sites with good examples of things similar.

Thanks in advance :)
Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Start' your query from the `IndividualTakingPart` table.

```
Dim Events = From itp in context.IndividualTakingPart _
             Where itp.Individual_id = 1 _
             Select itp.Events
```

**Update** (in response to comments below)

**You need to have a primary key on the joining table to enable the associations to the other tables.**

Comment: where it selects the itp.Events it doesent have acces to the events table only the ids that are in the individualtakingparts table

Comment: @Houlahan - check that your datacontext has been created properly. You should have access to the Individual and Events tables from IndividualTakingPart.

Comment: as far as i can see its set up correctly i am right in thinking that the context can be defined as Dim db As New SailMembersDataContext?

Comment: @Houlahan - yes that's right. Look in you `SailMembersDataClasses.designer.vb` file (hidden under the `dbml` file). Find the `IndividualTakingPart` class. There should be 2 `<Global.System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute ...>'s` linking the table to the other tables. Do you see that?

Comment: Also, you should add a primary key to the IndividualTakingPart table - whether its another id column or a composite key comprising the 2 existing foreign keys. Not sure if that will fix the associations but its worth a try.

Comment: Thank you it was the fact that i didn't have a primary key on the bridging table

Comment: @Houlahan, no problem. I've updated my answer to make the solution easier to find for anyone else who stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you needs something like this.

```
Public Function GetEventsByIndividual(ByVal individual As Individual) As IEnumerable(Of Event)

    Return individual.IndividualTakingParts _
                     .SelectMany(Function(itp) itp.Events)

End Function
```

Comment: that would be perfect but .Select isnt part of the individual class :/

Comment: for some reason it says that the individualTakingPart isnt part of the individual table im wondering if my relationship is correct now?